# Configuring network settings in Linux via gsettings/script/terminal

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, settings, system-settings, gsettings

How do I configure network settings--like identity, IPv4 format (address, netmask, gateway, DNS), security and passwords--in Ubuntu 18.04 through a script?

I couldn't find any gsettings schemas for it. I'd very much appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi.. you want to create a new one or edit the existing one?

Comment: There are command line tools available for network manager. If you are still using network manager would you like to continue using?

Comment: @PRATAP , firstly add a new profile and later edit it with updates.

Comment: @mchid yes, I'll prefer to continue using the same network manager default with ubuntu 18.04.. but again it's just a preference, if there are better ways to work around it, I'm open to em..

Comment: @PRATAP , create a new script, if thats what you meant.

Comment: @frankenstein Thanks, the answer is below. If you don't already know, you can list  available wireless and ethernet devices by running `ifconfig`. These examples use `enp1s0` for the ethernet device and `wlp2s0` for wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use the `nmcli` tool to edit connections through NetworkManager.**

For example, say you want to create an ethernet connection for device: `enp1s0`.

- IP: 192.168.1.10
- gateway: 192.168.1.1
- DNS: 8.8.8.8
- connection name: "net-enp1s0"

```bsh
sudo nmcli con add con-name "net-enp1s0" ifname enp1s0 type ethernet ipv4.method manual ip4 192.168.1.10/24 gw4 192.168.1.1 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
```

or as a script (you will need to use `sudo` to run this script):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
nmcli con add \
con-name "net-enp1s0" \
ifname enp1s0 \
type ethernet \
ipv4.method manual \
ip4 192.168.1.10/24 \
gw4 192.168.1.1 \
ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
```

These are the options:

- `con` = connection
- `add` = add
- `con-name "net-enp1s0"` = connection id
- `ifname enp1s0` = connection interface-name
- `type ethernet` = connection type
- `ipv4.method manual` = use static IP
- `ip4 192.168.1.10/24` = local ipv4 address and netmask ([24=255.255.255.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks))
- `gw4 192.168.1.1` = gateway
- `ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8` = DNS server

---

**You can also edit an existing connection.**

Configuration file for our "net-enp1s0" connection is: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/net-enp1s0`. The file should look like this:

```bsh
[connection]
id=net-enp1s0
uuid=5099a1ae-1ae0-42d7-acf8-178ef3772f4f
type=ethernet
interface-name=enp1s0
permissions=

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.1.10/24,192.168.1.1
dns=8.8.8.8;
dns-search=
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

If you edit the configuration file for a network, you can run the following command to apply the changes:

```bsh
sudo nmcli con reload
```

---

**The following example is for a WPA wireless connection with PSK named "coffee-shop" on a network named "freewifi" using the password "freepassword":**

```bsh
sudo nmcli con add con-name "coffee-shop" type wifi ifname wlp2s0 ssid "freewifi" -- wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk "freepassword" ipv4.method manual ip4 192.168.1.10/24 gw4 192.168.1.1 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
```

Here it is as a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
nmcli con add \
con-name "coffee-shop" \
type wifi \
ifname wlp2s0 \
ssid "freewifi" \
-- wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk \
wifi-sec.psk "freepassword" \
ipv4.method manual \
ip4 192.168.1.10/24 \
gw4 192.168.1.1 \
ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
```

Links:

- [Wifi example based on this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387210/70847) by user [@cody-G](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/206995/cody-%EF%BC%A7)
- [NetworkManager nmcli documentation at gnome.org](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html)
- [CertDepot](https://www.certdepot.net) tutorial ["RHEL7: Configure IPv4 addresses"](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-ipv4-addresses/)

Also, this [Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#nmcli_examples) has a list of `nmcli` examples.

The CertDepot tutorial is for RedHat but pretty much all of the `nmcli` stuff applies to Ubuntu. However, Ubuntu configuration files are in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and you can directly edit these files.