# Why is nmcli not configuring device?

Tags: nmcli

I'm new to nmcli and trying to figure out how to create an eth0 connection. `sudo nmcli con` prints the following:

```
NAME       UUID     TYPE      DEVICE
MyWlan0    ...      wifi      wlan0
MyEth0     ...      ethernet  --
```

No matter what command I give, my MyEth0 connection will not show eth0 under DEVICE above (just '--') and, as a result, I'll get the following error when I try `sudo nmcli con up MyEth0`:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device lo not available because device is strictly unmanaged).
```

This is how I created the connection:

```
sudo nmcli con add con-name MyEth0 type ethernet ifname eth0
```

I've also tried modifying it with the following sorts of commands:

```
sudo nmcli con mod MyEth0 connection.interface-name eth0
```

Running `sudo nmcli con show MyEth0 connection | grep eth0` does indicate that the connection.interface-name is eth0, but it does not appear this way according to the behavior described above.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth0
       serial: dc:a6:32:27:84:45
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=v2.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: dc:a6:32:27:84:46
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.18 firmware=01-6a2c8ad4 ip=192.168.1.201 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1182881/739431

Comment: I had seen that link. It does not address my problem

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: @chili555 ok, done

Comment: @chili555 Did the extra requested info prove informative?

Answer (score 7):

This is because since Ubuntu 18.04, the network configuration file has changed from interfaces to netplan, and you need to use `apt install network-manager` again modify `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`like this

```
network:
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

This allows the network configuration to point to NetworkManager,then use `netplan apply` load this file.
you can use `nmcli device status` check if the configuration is in effect.gook luck!

Comment: I remember doing this before, but it seems that an update broke. Is there a way to do this that is not broken by updates?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

https://serverfault.com/questions/880950/network-issue-ifup-says-unknown-interface

```
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Followed by:

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

Answer (score 0):

Your networking might be disabled. to solve the issue run `nmcli networking on`. This will enable networking control by NetworkManager and make your network interface manageable. All interfaces managed by NetworkManager are deactivated when networking is disabled.

Answer (score -2):

Network manager normally only manages wifi connections.

change in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

to

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Restart NetworkManager.service and nm-applet

and try again.

Comment: Untrue. Network Manager controls any and all network connections including ethernet.

Comment: Tried that. No effect.

Comment: sorry my knowledge is like me sometimes outdated. :D  This change do only work, when an /etc/network/interfaces is in use. I'am in the wrong system.